# Install vmware-tools using yum in vmware fusion

Tags: centos, utilities, vmware

I added vmware-tools repo [1] to my virtual CentOS box. What is the exact set of packages I have to install?

The rationale is to be able to update vmware-tools using yum.

Environment:

Host OS: Mac OS X 10.8

Guest OS: CentOS-6.4-x86_64

VMware-fusion: 5.0.3

[1] http://packages.vmware.com/tools/esx/latest/repos/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a GUI in the virtual machine, install `vmware-tools-esx`. If your virtual machine has no GUI, install `vmware-tools-esx-nox`. Either way, this will pull in all the necessary dependencies.

Comment: I accept you answer, as vmware-fusion reports tools as installed. Do you have any vendor resource stating that vmware-tools-esx are compatible across all vmware products or otherwise fit here? Thanks!

Comment: VMware documentation? I don't think so. Though I've been running this in Workstation 9 virtual machines for close to a year.